What implications does Mutable metadata have?
I am in a CTO of a group, and we potentially have some suspicious activity unfolding. We believe the CTO was a ploy from the original dev who still held large amounts of supply from the minted wallet address.
My question is what can the developer do with mutable metadata on the contract? Besides change the ticker and name…can they delete or fork transactions from the log?
We have speculations that there are buys/sells missing from the transaction log that are not corresponding with the candle actions on the chart by any means. A member has also seen sales up to $1000+ which after refreshing the Dex page were then gone.
We have a lot of new pair wallets buying and selling tokens but they all trace back to the same wallets who are exchanging them these tokens. They are doing mini pump and dumps almost like an organized team.
Also these wallets are all linked to other projects with mutable metadata in their contracts as well (again not sure if mutable has anything to do with this). Whenever they have for example a $340 and $270 buy in our coin, there is always an inverse $340 and $270 sale in another token at the exact same timestamp, and they keep repeating this multiple times a day.
I am not educated in what the developer has access to or not, so I would love some input on this please!

This looks like wash trading activity to change the token price or some arbitrage activity. Anyone that owns tokens can theoretically do things like that.
If someone has the metadata update authority all they can do is change the metadata, icon, name and uri.
But often when a token is created the update authority is also the mint and/or freeze authority. So if someone has that key they could for example mint more tokens or freeze token accounts
